# Copy clipboard in Python only if text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyperclip

I'm doing a tool to store clipboard texts in a list and is there a way in Python to check the data in the clipboard if it is a text or file across multiple platforms. Currently, I'm using `pyperclip.copy()` which gives me the clipboard data but if a file is copied it returns me the name of the file like `sample file.py`. Is there a way to check only if the clipboard is text?

Comment: I assume you checked the readme https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip So you should know that pyperclip “Currently only handles plaintext.” Your options are quite limited.

Comment: do you have any other module suggestion that can find in my specs? @barny

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic on StackOverflow